# Vue2 Router vs Facebook Javascript SDK: Redirect URI

Tags: vuejs2, facebook-javascript-sdk, vue-router

I have a vue2 single-page-app. In an vue component, I try to use Facebook Javascript SDK to authenticate and use Graph API.

In a method, I use this code to connect to Facebook

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxx',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.10'
    });

    console.log(FB);


    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    //js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js";
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk/debug.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

When the app executes the method FB.getLoginStatus, I get the error message “**URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings.**”.
I know that I have to go to the settings of my facebook app and enter the redirect url into **OAuth Redirect URIs**.

My problem is, I have done this. The callback url is **https://localhost/myapp/public/api/facebook/callback**. So I guess I'm too stupid to find out the correct callback url... Any ideas how to find out this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the vue router history mode.

In my router js file, I added this line:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history', // that did the trick
    routes: [ ... ]
})
```

There may be a better solution, but it works for me...